# Two rotated images on top of each other on same page

Tags: floats, subfloats, rotating

I'm trying to embed two images on top of each other with both of them being rotated. I also want them to be on the same page (kinda like how two a5 papers fit on one a4).

I've tried to play around with `sidewaysfigure` but I wasn't able to get to my requested setup.

EDIT: added concept image for extra clarity!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Two images (horizontally) next to each other in a `landscape` environment?

Comment: One can use landscape (pdflscape) and \afterpage (afterpage) to put two two figures on one rotated page.  Use [p] for figures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\centering
\includegraphics[angle=90,width=\linewidth,height=.499\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-golden-upright}\vfill%
\includegraphics[angle=90,width=\linewidth,height=.499\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-10x16}%
\end{document}
```